# Code 12 on a graphics card in a Thunderbolt 3 eGPU-enclosure

Tags: windows, graphics-card, pci-express, thunderbolt, enclosures

So, I'm trying to do the eGPU thing. I'm running Windows 10 (freshly installed, literally 15 minutes ago, no changes whatsoever) on a 2016 MacBook Pro (15", the one with two full PCIe busses over four Thunderbolt 3 ports).

I've connected an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 over Thunderbolt 3, using the [Razer Core eGPU enclosure](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10137/razer-core-thunderbolt-3-egfx-chassis-499399-amd-nvidia-shipping-in-april). Unfortunately, I'm getting the dreaded “Code 12” error: “This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use.”

[image]

I've seen some advice to manually assign ‘code-12’ devices a new IRQ; but under the Device Manager, it doesn't even seem to *have* an IRQ number; nor does it show up with a address-mapping range under “I/O” devices.

[image]

Other things suggest downgrading the BIOS (?!); but this is a Mac. It doesn't even *have* a BIOS, just BIOS emulation — definitely nothing I can dive into and toggle memory-allocation settings, right?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same resource shortfall on an XPS 13 9350 with a Razer Core V1 & an R9 Fury, ended up using `Action -> Devices by devices by connection` in Device Manager with the GPU selected and working my way up the PCIe device tree, running `Action -> Uninstall device` + `Action -> Scan for hardware changes` for each node.  Eventually for one of those device nodes the uninstall + scan got the GPU working.

Comment: I did this a dozen times and I couldn't get it to work. I think you were lucky. I am using an XPS 9750